# Valores repetidos en JSON

Tags: java, android, json

Estoy cargando en JSON unos valores y me gustaría controlar y borrar los duplicados:

```
    public void loadEventos(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.gamedata), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String data=prefs.getString("eventos","");
    eventos.clear();
    if(!data.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);
            if(jo.has("eventos")){
                JSONArray ja=jo.getJSONArray("eventos");
                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                    if (!ja.getString(i).isEmpty()) {
                        Evento ev=new Evento(ja.getString(i));
                        Log.d(GLOBALES.TAG,"eventosString="+eventos.get(i).toString());
                        Log.d(GLOBALES.TAG,"eventosArray="+ja.getString(i));
                        if(ev.getFinalizacion()>System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                            eventos.add(ev);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuando dices borrar los valores duplicados te refieres a no incluirlos en eventos o a borrarlos del JSON?

Comment: No incluirlos en el evento

Comment: Ok, Pues te vale con que eventos sea un Set. Que por defecto no puede contener valores repetidos. Si eventos tiene que ser una lista habría que buscar un sistema de ordenación y búsqueda en la lista para descartar los repetidos y hacerlo de una forma eficiente. En ese caso te pondría una solución abajo.

Comment: Eventos tiene que ser un arraylist. Un list<Evento>.

Comment: Como dice @Héctor puedes añadir los eventos a un Set y si lo que necesitas es un list, puedes pasar el set a List una vez ya se hayan quitado los eventos repetidos.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892360/convert-set-to-list-without-creating-new-list aqui tienes como pasar de un Set a un List

Comment: Si lo quieres hacer con un list sin tener que crear un set, sustituye el eventos.add(ev) por if(!eventos.contains(ev)) eventos.add(ev). Con esto, antes de almacenar el evento compruebas si ya existe y si ya existe no lo introduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puesto que obligatoriamente eventos debe ser una Lista lo mejor que puedes hacer hacer es determinar si el elemento que vas a insertar existe entre los elementos de la lista antes de insertarlo. La forma más rápida de buscar elementos dentro de una lista de un tamaño bastante grandes es una búsqueda binaria. Pero tiene el problema de que las listas deben estar ordenadas. Ordenar gasta tiempo en la ejecución. Así que deberías hacerte una pregunta:

**¿`eventos` puede llegar a tener muchos registros?**

Si la respuesta es sí. Lo más óptimo es ordenar la lista una vez, Luego, buscar el registro nuevo en tu lista ordenada cada vez que vayas a hacer una inserción y si no está, insertarlo de forma ordenada. De esta forma la lista siempre está ordenada.

1. Ordenar la lista: Puedes ordenar una lista mediante al función [`Collections.sort(List<T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html). Ahora bien, la clase Evento debe implementar [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). Es una interfaz en el que se implementa un método, en ese método indicas como ordenar la lista. Para muestar un ejemplo:

   ```
   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override
   public int compareTo(NodeElement arg0) {
       return this.getId().compareTo(arg0.getId());
   }
   ```

   Una vez implementada la interfaz podrías llamar al método en la primera línea del método:

   ```
   Collections.sort(eventos);
   ```
2. Búsqueda del elemento: Puedes buscar el elemento llamando al siguiente método    [binarySearch(List> list, T key)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) que devuelve la posición en la que se encuentra el elemento o -(punto correcto de inserción) si no lo encuentra

   ```
   int i = Collections.binarySearch(eventos,ev);
   if(i < 0){
      // Inserción ordenada
   }
   ```
3. Inserción ordenada: Por último solo queda insertar de forma ordenada el elemento. Puesto que `binarySearch` devuelve la posición en negativo en la que debería estar el elemento menos uno. Basta con guardar ese entero y restarle 1:

   ```
    eventos.add((-i)-1, ev);
   ```
4. Ejemplo

   Te dejo un ejemplo con strings:

   ```
   public class MainTest {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           List<String> strings = new ArrayList();
           strings.add("b");
           strings.add("d");
           strings.add("h");

           Collections.sort(strings);

           int i = Collections.binarySearch(strings, "a");

           strings.add((-i)-1,"a");

           i = Collections.binarySearch(strings, "c");
           strings.add((-i)-1,"c");

           i = Collections.binarySearch(strings, "y");
           strings.add((-i)-1,"y");

           System.out.println(strings);
       }
   }
   ```

Si la respuesta es No, te vale con sobreescribir el método equals de Evento

1. Sobrescribir el método `equals()` de Evento para identificar qué elemento es igual a qué otro.
2. Crear el if:

   ```
   if(!eventos.contains(ev)){
      eventos.add(ev);
   }
   ```